# problems installing Erlang/OTP

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, makefile, erlang-otp

I'm trying to install Erlang/OTP following the documentation at
http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html.
I'm having problems building the Erlang/OTP release.
When I run `make`, I get:

```
Makefile:247: /home/otp_src_17.0/make/i686-pc-linux-gnu/otp_ded.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/amiro/otp_src_17.0/make/i686-pc-linux-gnu/otp_ded.mk'.  Stop.
```

Has anyone here encountered this kind of problem?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 4):

That error occurred while building the Erlang package from scratch.
Why don't you try to install Erlang using `apt-get`? The Ubuntu repositories already have the recent Erlang packages.

Just type and execute the following command on a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install erlang erlang-doc
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/190612/how-to-install-erlang-in-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 3):

You may try download OTP from here https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html for your system. Or trying this http://freshbrewedcode.com/bryanhunter/2014/04/10/hurray-for-erlang-17-0/ method - in this script lists all the required packages.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have a three ways for Erlang install:

1 - U can try install Erlang by `apt-get`, but for Ubuntu the version Erlang will be - 18:

```
$ sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
```

1.1 - If u cannot install Erlang, try remove Erlang from your computer before installing:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove esl-erlang
$ sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
```

2 - U can try download and install any Erlang versions, use Erlang Solutions https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html, but you should know that in version 19+ you can receive the error `WX Failed loading` - this mean that Erlang will be work but WX cannot be worked, but this can be also fixed, please follow the link https://elixirforum.com/t/observer-start-is-not-working-on-ubuntu/6018

3 - U can try use http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html follow step by step, but please be sure that you downloaded the version for installation under the architecture of your processor - in other case  you will can experience installation problems

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem during the installation of erlang with evm (erlang version manager) on Ubuntu. 
I solved it installing those packages: 
automake autoconf libreadline-dev libncurses-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev libtool unixodbc-dev xsltproc

Then I installed erlang with documentation, without problems: 
evm install OTP_21.1 --with-docs

I hope this helps.