# Having trouble when installing Erlang/OTP

Tags: erlang

I have followed the steps from this link:
http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html

But when I try to run 'make' I get an error saying

```
Makefile:247 .... no such file or directory
make: ***no rule to make target
```

Here is the same question but without an accepted answer.
[problems installing Erlang/OTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309802/problems-installing-erlang-otp)

Comment: 1. Consider installing from repository
2. Can you describe more precise what steps you perform and what error you get (with context)
3. Does your configure step complete successfully?

Comment: I unpack the zip and set the two variables (ERL_TOP and LANG) then generate the confrigure scripts. After that I run ./configure. All that completes successfully but then I run make and I get the output that is written above.

Comment: Does it actually print you `...` and not some path in `Makefile:247 .... no such file or directory`?

Comment: Also what system you are building on?

Comment: Yes, the path is where the ... are. It goes like this: /home/mininet/otp_src_17.5./make/i686-pc-linux-gnu/otp_ded.mk
I am running Mininet/Ubuntu VM.

Comment: On ubuntu just install from repository as sugested in the linked answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [problems installing Erlang/OTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309802/problems-installing-erlang-otp)

Comment: I have tried it just now. I get the same error. And also when running ./configure it says: `configure: error: No curses library functions found
configure: error: /bin/bash '/home/mininet/Downloads/otp_src_R15B03/erts/configure' failed for erts`

Comment: can you tell your operating system / version ? people cannot guess what operating system you have so they cannot offer any help

Comment: @user2472368 You need to install curses library, i.e. libncurses5-dev or add --without-termcap to ./configure command